# React: How to render same page that includes multiple components and forms for 2 types of user with different permissions?

Tags: reactjs, render, use-context

I have a page with some components inside it. I want to render this page conditionally based on user's role(mentor/student), and each of them have access to edit just some components but can see all the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is conditional rendering, there are multiple ways of achieving it... a naïve one is:

```
import React from "react"

export default function Example() {
  // this can be replaced by something more complex
  const credentials = "1"

  if (credentials === "1") {
    return <UserForm />
  }

  return <AdminForm />
}
```

Also, you can add conditional rendering inside your component...

```
import React from "react"

export default function UserForm({ credentials }) {

  return (
    <div>
    {credentials === "1" ? <div>Hi</div> : <div>Ciao</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```